# Cannot save the code to a Lightning Component - Keep getting "The Markup in the document following the root element" ERROR . What am I doing wrong?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, iframe

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    
<aura:attribute name="iframeUrl" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="width" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="height" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="scrolling" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="frameBorder" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="style" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="sandbox" type="String" />

<iframe src="{!v.iframeUrl}"
    width="{!v.width}"
    height="{!v.height}"
    style="{!v.style}"
    frameBorder="{!v.frameBorder}"
    sandbox="{!v.sandbox}"
    scrolling="{!v.scrolling}"/>
</aura:component>
<design:component label="iFrame Component">
    <design:attribute name="iframeUrl" label="Source URL (HTTPS only)" default="https://cnn.com"/>
    <design:attribute name="width" label="Width" default="100%"/>
    <design:attribute name="height" label="Height" default="500px"/>
    <design:attribute name="style" label="Style" default="border: none; overflow: scroll;"/>
    <design:attribute name="scrolling" label="Scrolling" default="auto"/>
    <design:attribute name="frameBorder" label="Frame Border" default="0"/>
    <design:attribute name="sandbox" label="Frame Border" default="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-forms"/>
</design:component
```

Comment: Did you paste the entire component. I see it is missing the `</aura:component>`.

Answer (score 0):

The provided code contains markup from both Component and design files from the Aura Bundle.

Take out the `<design:component>....</design:component>` and put in the design file of the bundle.

Also the `</design:component>` not closed properly.